# What about anonymous users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have some questions for you today.

1. What is considered an anonymous user?
2. What happens if I link a credential to an anonymous user? Is it still considered anonymous?
3. What about user registration in relation to anonymous users? Can I simply link the anonymous user to an email or any other credential?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`What is considered an anonymous user?`

The Anonymous user is a system account that does not require authentication using credentials. It is disabled in Appian, by default.

`What happens if I link a credential to an anonymous user? Is it still considered anonymous?`

Yes it will consider as anonymous user after link a credentials to an anonymous user.

`What about user registration in relation to anonymous users? Can I simply link the anonymous user to an email or any other credential?`

Yes you can simply link anonymous user to an email credential.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What is considered an anonymous user?

The `isAnonymous` property of a user is set to true, if that user (only) signed in with the [anonymous authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) of Firebase Authentication.

> 2. What happens if I link a credential to an anonymous user? Is it still considered anonymous?

When you link another provider, the `isAnonymous` property becomes false. Even if you later unlink the other provider, the `isAnonymous` property remains false.

> 3. What about user registration in relation to anonymous users? Can I simply link the anonymous user to an email or any other credential?

You can indeed [link email credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking#link-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account) to a user account that was created through the anonymous authentication provider. You can also [set email/password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) for such an account through the Admin SDK.